# How to show method argument hints all the time in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea hints/shows method parameter names when I type hardcoded value, however, when I write a variable instead, it doesn't show the hint.

[image]

As you can see here, it says `expected` before `50`, but there is no hint before `creditor.getAvailableFunds()` method.

[image]

How to enable these hints all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure it with the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inlay Hints | Java | **Non-literals in case of multiple parameters with the same type** option:

[image]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Андрей